# VSCode: Prettier does not work with Dart Flutter

Tags: node.js, dart, visual-studio-code, prettier

I am using `Dart` and `Node.js`. I tried to auto format `Node.js` with `Prettier`. However, VSCode auto formats `Dart` file but it does not format `JavaScript` with `Prettier`.

[image]

Under the screen, it says Prettier on JavaScript. When I touch the setting and set it to `Prettier` for auto format, `Prettier` works and it auto format JS files but `Dart` auto format does not work.

How can I set VSCode to auto format Dart and JS files without switching settings everytime?

VSCode Setup

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.rulers": [
            80
        ],
        "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
        "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
        "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
        "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
    },
    "workbench.preferredHighContrastColorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "dart.openDevTools": "flutter",
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    }
}
```

!!!! Solution

```
"editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.dart-code",
```

You need to add this line to setting.json Dart part. And then set your default formatter to Prettier!

Comment: Have you set Prettier as your global default formatter or just for javascript/JSON?

Comment: It is set with the default formatter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't set Prettier as VS Code's global default formatter. Set to only be the default formatter where Javascript is concerned. Open your settings JSON and add the following:

```json
{
  ...
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  }
}
```

Comment: This opt-in seems suboptimal since Prettier [supports more languages/syntaxes](https://prettier.io/docs/en/index.html) than those.

Comment: @rightdroid If you use Prettier for any of those other things, you can either add those to the opt-in or you can go the other route and opt-out of languages you don't want Prettier to cover. That said, personally I'd rather opt-in every language it does support than opt-out every language it doesn't.

Comment: The reason I mentioned it is I don't think you need to opt-out from anything that Prettier doesn't support: it will not try to format files it doesn't know how to. I have Prettier set as default formatter and Dart language extension installed. Prettier for example will handle json files in that project, but not dart files.

Comment: @rightdroid This question exists because OP was having issues with Prettier overriding the formatted from the Dart extension and was trying to format Dart, which obviously it has no idea how to do. Maybe it was a configuration mistake or a bug in the Prettier extension that has since been fixed, but the solution still stands for people running into similar issues.

Comment: Your solution is great for showing people how to set language-specific formatters, and it technically solves the problem. As I said in the beginning, it is suboptimal. You're crippling your Prettier extension for no apparent reason (unless your aim *is* to cripple it). You could solve the OP's problem by specifying to use Dart extension for dart files. 

`"[dart]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.dart-code",
  },`

Obvioulsy your milage varies, but if you code Node.js projects, it makes no sense to set Dart as your default formatter.

Answer (score 5):

I took a combination of the answer and comments above and used it to solve the problem I had, which was Firebase Cloud Function JavaScript/Typescript and Flutter/Dart code in the same VSCode project.

1. Create a .vscode folder in the root of your project.
2. Create a settings.json file inside of it.
3. Add the following and tweak to your liking. In the main VSCode settings, you can find a cog in the left gutter next to each setting that has a "Copy setting to JSON" menu item, which you can then paste into the below and adjust to override the application-level settings.
4. Decide whether to .gitignore your new folder or share it with your team.
5. Restart VSCode

```
{
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[dart]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.dart-code" },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```